# Jump to a tab using the tab name as a variable from a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am working on a forecasting model.  A dropdown with three options puts one of these numbers in a specific cell 1a, 1b, 1c (this corresponds to tabs named accordingly 1a, 1b, 1c).

I want to click on a box and jump to the tab named in the specific cell.

I need to set the worksheet name to a variable contained in a cell so I can jump to three different tabs from the same place depending on which name 1a, 1b, 1c appears in the specific cell.

Comment: What do you mean by click on a box? Do you mean a button?

Answer (score 1):

#### Formula only Solution

You can use a formula for this. For example if you have the sheet name `Sheet2` in cell A1 and write the following formula somewhere:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & A1 & "!A1","Link")
```

Then this link will open `Sheet2`. If the value in A1 then changes to `Sheet3` the link will automatically change to open `Sheet3`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Controls to Activate Another Worksheet

- If you're going to create a button, then copy the following code to a standard module, e.g. `Module1`, and assign `jump` to the button (`right-click > Assign Macro`).

**Button**

```
Option Explicit

Sub jump()
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const cAddr As String = "A1"
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets(.Worksheets(wsName).Range(cAddr).Value).Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

- If you're going to create a command button then copy the following code to the appropriate sheet module e.g. `Sheet1` (`Design Mode > double-click`).

**CommandButton**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const cAddr As String = "A1"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Range(cAddr).Value).Activate
End Sub
```

- Change the constants appropriately.

Comment: Sub LINK_1a()

'===============================
' SCREEN UPDATE
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'===============================



Dim strSheet As String
strSheet = Sheets("MAP").Range("B7")
Sheets(strSheet).Activate


'===============================
' SCREEN UPDATE
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'===============================
End Sub

Comment: Sub LINK_1a()
Dim strSheet As String
strSheet = Sheets("MAP").Range("B7")
Sheets(strSheet).Activate
End Sub

Comment: @SyllyOBrien Please don't post code in comments. it is useless! If this is something you have a question with than this should be part of your original post. You can edit it to add it there and ask something. If this is considered to be a solution post it ans an answer using the anwser button. • You might want to check out the [tour] or the [help].